# Error on mocking multiple service(SSM, SES, SNS ) with Jest - lambda nodejs function unit testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs

I am trying to mock multiple service in lambda  nodejs function with Jest in Jest but continue to get this error. Is there any better way to AWS lambda functions using jest?

> ReferenceError: mockSsm is not defined

Lambda function Index.js:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES();
var sns = new aws.SNS();
var ssm = new aws.SSM();
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
var envPath = process.env.ssm_store;
var environment = {};


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var envReq = getParameterFromSystemManager(envPath);
    envReq.then(async (env) => {

        environment = env;

        let userName = event.userName;
        let emailId = event.emailId;
        let emailSubject = event.emailSubject;
        let message = event.message;
        let phoneNumber = event.phoneNumber;

        let lang  = await getUserLanguage(userName);
        sendEmail(emailId, emailSubject, message);
        sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('-error', err);
    });
};


function getUserLanguage(username) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminGetUser(paramWithData, (errDetail, UserAttributes) => {
            if (errDetail) {
                resolve('error');
            } else {
                resolve(UserAttributes.preferredLang);
            }
        });
    });
}

function sendEmail(to, subject, message) {
    ses.sendEmail(paramWithData, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

function sendSMS(phone, message) {
    sns.publish(paramWithData, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}


function getParameterFromSystemManager(ssmpath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ssm.getParametersByPath(paramWithData, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(false);
            }
            else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Test file Index.spec.js:

```
const myHandler = require('../index.js').handler;

var aws = require('aws-sdk');

const mockSsm = jest.fn();
const mockSes = jest.fn();
const mockSns = jest.fn();
const mockCognito = jest.fn();

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
    return {
        SSM: jest.fn(() => ({
            getParametersByPath: mockSsm
        })),
        SES: jest.fn(() => ({
          other1: mockSes
        })),
        SNS: jest.fn(() => ({
          other2: mockSns
        })),
        CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: jest.fn(() => ({
          other3: mockCognito
        }))
    };
});

describe('myHandler', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should return data', async () => {
    const mResponse = { data: 'testSSMResults' };
    mockSsm.mockImplementation((params) => {
      return {
          promise() {
              return Promise.resolve(mResponse)
          }
      };
    });
    const ssmparamValue = await myFunctions.getParameterFromSystemManager('');
    expect(ssmparamValue).toEqual(mResponse);
  });
});
```